# How to define an Aggregator in Camel after using a ProducerTemplate?

Tags: csv, split, apache-camel

I have a route that processes csv files and inserts them as records into the database. Since it's a huge csv-file and the Camel csv-splitter ran out of memory we had to write our own splitter. I wrote the splitter using a ProducerTemplate.

The route to process the csv looks a bit like this:

```
<route id="processCsvRoute">
    <from ref="inbox" />
    <to uri="bean:csvBean?method=process"/>
</route>
```

In the csvBean we do the splitting and finally execute the following java code for every csv-line (a csv line results in a product object).

```
producer.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:csvAggregator", product, "ID", csv.getFilename());
```

No the csvAggregator-route picks up the csv:

```
<route id="csvAggregator">
<from uri="direct:csvAggregator" />
<aggregate strategyRef="exchangeAggregatorStrategy"
               completionSize="10000"
               completionInterval="10000"
               parallelProcessing="true">
        <correlationExpression>
            <header>ID</header>
        </correlationExpression>
        <to uri="bean:batchInsertBean"/>
    </aggregate>
</route>
```

Is there a way to define the aggregator in the processCsvRoute? My solution is working, but it doesn't feel right I have to create a separate route for it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just enable streaming mode on the splitter, then it reads the CSV file "line by line" and you won't run out of memory.

The documentation has more details: http://camel.apache.org/splitter

```
<split streaming="true" ...>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Do you mean splitting the csv file on a newline and then feed it to the marshaller?

http://camel.apache.org/csv.html is the csv reader I used before, but it read the whole file and I can't figure out how to combine that with a splitter (without splitting on a newline with a tokenizer)

Comment: Yes you would need to split first on a line by line basis, and then marshal to CSV each line.

Comment: Ok, that might be a solution. But right now the csvBean is doing additional processing. Is it possible to merge the two routes into one? Right now we have to work with the direct:csvAggregator endpoint and create a separate route for it, that doesn't feel right :-)